# How to configure systemd $PATH to match user $PATH

Tags: systemd, path

I run a Next.js frontend on a VM using systemd. My workflow for making systemd services is usually:

1. Make the application work from the user shell (`ec2-user` in this case)
2. Write a unit file which does the same, and uses the same user

However, the service did not work as expected, due to differences in `$PATH`.

Indeed, `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` contain code that extends `$PATH`. This configuration has been done automatically by tools like [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

So I ended up making an ugly unit file to match the same `$PATH` that I have in my user shell:

```
[Unit]
Description=Web App Frontend
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ec2-user
Group=ec2-user
Environment="PATH=/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/shims:/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/bin:/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin"
WorkingDirectory=/home/ec2-user/web-app-frontend
ExecStart=/home/ec2-user/.nvm/versions/node/v20.11.0/bin/yarn start

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Is there a cleaner way to solve this?**

Answer (score 0):

Answer was provided by [user Sienna Dragon on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21043643/sienna-dragon). I'm copying their answer below:

It seems that you want your systemd service to have the same environment as when you open a termina. You can achieve this using PAM (Pluggable Authentication Modules) to load the user's environment. Just add `PAMName=login` to your `.service` file. Like this :

```
[Service]
PAMName=login
Type=simple
ExecStart=/path/to/your/command
```

This will enables your systemd load envirment using PAM login module.